# FutureBuilder : The method '&' was called on nul

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I need to retrieve just one document from `Firestore` and store its data inside a custom class called `Artista` .

To reach this I'm using a `FutureBuilder`. Its usage is not so clear for me but I think I'm using it fine, the problem is how to read documents data I guess because when the `FutureBuilder` is called this is the error :

```
The method '&' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: &(4294967295)
```

I think I'm not reading snapshot data in the right way, so the problem should be  the `Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot` factory method but I'll put the entire code.

Important information is : `cloud_firestore: ^2.4.0`

This is the StreamBuilder :

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          future: widget.database.getFutureArtistById(widget.name),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData && !(snapshot.data.exists)) {
              return Text("User does not exist");
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.data.exists &&
                snapshot.data != null) {
              Artista artistaTrovato = Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot);
              if (artistaTrovato != null) {
                print(artistaTrovato.toString());
              }
              return Artists_Showroom(
                  artistaCorrente: widget.artista,
                  database: widget.database,
                  lista: [artistaTrovato]);
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Center(
                  child: Container(
                child: Text("No user found"),
              ));
            else
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
          }),
```

This is the future to resolve :

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> getFutureArtistById(
      String id) async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("ids")
        .doc("tabs")
        .collection(id[0])
        .doc(id)
        .get();
  }
```

And this is how to read the snapshot (Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot) :

```
factory Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot(
      AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> doc) {
    return Artista(
      bio: doc.data.data()["bio"],
      regione: doc.data.data()["regione"],
      citta: doc.data.data()["citta"],
      comune: doc.data.data()["comune"],
      foto: doc.data.data()["foto"],
      nome: doc.data.data()["nome"],
      settore: doc.data.data()["settore"],
      lavoro: doc.data.data()["lavoro"],
      progetti: doc.data.data()["progetti"],
      id: doc.data.data()['id'],
      posts: doc.data.data()["posts"],
    );
  }
```

Am I reading it fine? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The below code should be working. I changed condition priority;

old

```dart
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                 snapshot.data.exists && snapshot.data != null
                )
```

new

```dart
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data.exists
                )
```

```dart
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          future: widget.database.getFutureArtistById(widget.name),
          builder: (BuildContext context,
              AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Error');
            } else if (snapshot.hasData && !(snapshot.data.exists)) {
              return Text("User does not exist");
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done &&
                snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data.exists
                ) {
              Artista artistaTrovato = Artista.fromDocumentSnapshot(snapshot);
              if (artistaTrovato != null) {
                print(artistaTrovato.toString());
              }
              return Artists_Showroom(
                  artistaCorrente: widget.artista,
                  database: widget.database,
                  lista: [artistaTrovato]);
            } else if (!snapshot.hasData)
              return Center(
                  child: Container(
                child: Text("No user found"),
              ));
            else
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
          }),
```

Comment: You're right but the problem was elsewhere, solved and yes it works I was reading the wrong collection :S